# Woocommerce Order cart array by cat and sub cat

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi we are trying to sort the Woo Cart by Main product category and list under the products in that category.  Like below:

Wheel Parts

- spokes 12
- Tyre's

Frame

- Y Frame
- X Frame
- Z Frame

Seat

- Seat 1
- Seat 2

We have managed to get to display by cat order but it is not ordering them into Main Cat -> Sub Cat

We have the below code and trying to order cart array by cat and sub cat

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', function() {

    global $woocommerce;
    $products_in_cart = array();
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($item['data']->id, 'product_cat' );

        $products_in_cart[ $key ] = $terms[0]->name;
    }

    natsort( $products_in_cart );

    $cart_contents = array();
    foreach ( $products_in_cart as $cart_key => $product_title ) {
        $cart_contents[ $cart_key ] = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_key ];

    }
    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents = $cart_contents;

}, 100 );
```

Any one have any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Your code was correct but you had just `natsort` which returning 1 is causing the issue. You also need to sort categories by menu order. Please check the below code working perfectly.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', function() {

    global $woocommerce;
    $products_in_cart = array();
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($item['data']->id, 'product_cat' );
        $products_in_cart[ $key ] = $terms[0]->term_id;
    }
    // $categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', 'orderby=menu_order&hide_empty=1' );

    asort($products_in_cart);
    $cat_array = array();
    foreach ($products_in_cart as $key => $value) {
        $cat_array[$key] =get_term_by('id', $value, 'product_cat');
    }
    $mai_cat = [];
    $i=0;
    foreach ($cat_array as $parent_key => $parent_value) {
        if($parent_value->parent == 0)
        {
            $mai_cat[$parent_key] = $parent_value->term_id;
            foreach ($cat_array as $parent_key_sub => $parent_value_sub) {
                if($parent_value_sub->parent == $parent_value->term_id)
                {
                    $mai_cat[$parent_key_sub] = $parent_value_sub->term_id;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    $cart_contents = array();
    foreach ( $mai_cat as $cart_key => $product_title ) {
        $cart_contents[ $cart_key ] = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_key ];

    }
    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents = $cart_contents;
}, 100 );
```

Tested and works well

Comment: Hi thanks for this!  Its working for the products which have parent cat and sub, but we are using composite products as well and its not displaying them under their cat..

Comment: If there any way of excluding the reordering/sorting for 3 product categories but still add them to the cart the normal woo way? Cheers

Comment: What do you mean with "composite product" ? Are you using "Composite Products" extension of woocommerce ?

Comment: Yes we are using Composite Products along side normal products, its ordering the normal products fine, but messing the order of Composite products

Comment: There are [functions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/composite-products/composite-products-functions-reference/) that should be useful for composite products.